# RC Circuit with a non-ideal switch

Tags: voltage, capacitor, charging, voltage-source

We can find a lot of material regarding the charging of a capacitor. For example http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capchg.html and many more

It is just an ideal RC circuit. The initial current is V/R etc

However in real life we have an inductance and a voltage source that has some rise time and is not instantaneous

However, what if the rise time of my voltage source is quite bad, what if it is 300ns, or maybe even 1-2us. What is the analysis of the RC circuit then? What would the initial current, or maximum current then be?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you would involve your power supply's rise time. What does the power supply have to do with the dampening circuit in your own case? Can you give some details?

Comment: why are you bringing inductnce into the picture and then saying lets neglect it?

Comment: I brought inductance into the picture as I thought that by mentioning non-ideal voltage source/switch, then someone would also say why not include the inductance of the wires/PCB tracks. I have removed the bit about inductance from the original question.

I am asking this question because all the analysis of RC circuits assume the voltage rises instantaneously, whereas in real life you will always have some kind of rise time. If your switch is a small transistor maybe it is only 5ns, but if it is a manual switch then it will be much much more.

Comment: Try simulating it - LTSpice is free

Answer (score 1):

For a typical model of the RC circuit, the differential equation is:
$$
i + \frac{1}{RC}\frac{di}{dt} = \frac{V_s}{R}
$$
With the link you supplied, that is for the common solution when Vs steps from 0 to Vb at t=0.

But the equation is valid for other Vs(t) -- voltage source as a function of time.

About your question of a voltage source with a finite rise time, the simplest model would be Vs(t) being a function with a segment of linear rising voltage followed by a constant voltage. This is solvable analytically without much difficulty.